# xargs plus shell string manipulation vs sed

Tags: shell, sed, xargs

I am trying to summarise the file extensions in a directory recursively.

`find .| xargs -d "\n" -I@ echo "${@##.*}" | sort |uniq -c`

But this is giving me a series of blank lines.  Not what I wanted.

I am aware of:

`find . -type f | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c` from a similar question, but am curious about why my formulation doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish : are you trying to summarize file types based on _mime types_ or based on _extensions_ (these are two different things) ?

Comment: @Goro for a medium-sized directory I receive `-bash: /usr/bin/file: Argument list too long`

Comment: @don_crissti I'd like to know how to use both methods.  I realise there are differences, and prefer the mime types.  If the `file` command is taking too long, I'd revert to extension-based type.

Comment: ... if you want the mime types then `find . -type f -exec file --brief --mime-type {} \; | sort | uniq -c` should do. Your code also works if you use a `for` loop, e.g. for `f in **/*; do...`

Comment: @Tim what is the objective of the process, I mean what you would like to achieve by the end, more specifically why you are using `cut` `sort` and `uniq`? The commands seems to be meaningless in providing correct output for cut and sort. If you would please provide example of the desired output this will be very helpful for us to help

Comment: @Goro The `cut` removes unwanted extra detail from the `file` command; the  `sort` `uniq` were to achieve summarization. The aim of the command overall is to see how many text files, how many pdfs, how many ... files in my directories. But this question differs from others because it asks "what am i doing wrong" in suggesting another method; this is the *first* question i asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `find` to execute `file` for each file found.

```
find . -exec file -b {} \; |cut -f1|sort|uniq -c
```

edit

As @Ed-Nevile's comment below removing `cut` provides more detail for ASCII files.

```
find . -exec file -b {} \; |sort|uniq -c
```

Comment: Upvoting as you use -b, but I don't think you should cut the output since several different file types will begin with 'ASCII'.

Comment: I think `-exec file -b {} +` will reduce the number of `file` processes created.

Comment: Certainly will, great update, tks, I wanted to answer his original question as close as possible :-)

Comment: 1. Can you please say why `exec` is preferred here over `xargs`? and 2. Can you tell me what is wrong syntactically with my attempts using bash string manipulation?  I am trying not just to achieve a result, but also to understand why other methods don't work.